# Can you point me to current examples using NHibernate in an ASP.NET MVC2 app?

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2

Can anyone point me to any self-contained, complete, current reference materials/projects using NHibernate in an ASP.NET MVC2 application?

I have looked at Sharp Architecture, but I am not sure I need the complexity in that project. I certainly don't know enough about it to know if it is over-engineered for my purposes.

I would like to see more types of implementations to gauge the various ways people have skinned this cat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This video series on nHibernate is great and they are using MVC Storefront as the base for the work:

http://www.tekpub.com/production/nhibernate

Code is here:

http://github.com/robconery/Kona

Another great MVC Resource (if you need one) is their MVC Videos:

http://www.tekpub.com/production/aspmvc
and
http://www.tekpub.com/production/byob

I can't recommend them enough.

- Max Schilling

Answer (score 1):

Gave it to Max for just answering. :)

But, for the record, here's additional apps to consider, should you end up here:

- Sharp Architecture (the Northwind app
  is okay but lean, not typical
  enterprisey stuff)
- Who Can Help Me? (great stuff and
  kept up-to-date)
- FubuMVC has good sample apps (based
  on MVC not MVC2 at the time of this
  post)

Thanks.